# d3 TimeScale - how to set axis offset

Tags: d3.js

I just try to code a reusable chart in d3 to visualize our energy data. 
I use a TimeScale for the X-Axis. I can not use a OrdinalScale (no discrete domain) and so I have to calculate "RangeBand" etc. by myself.

Problem: My bars overlap the chart - what is the best method to prevent this?. 
I think one way would be to set an offset in the X-Axis domain - here are my code snippets (which are hopefully clear..):

```
    // get X-Axis Min from all channels
    var tsMin = d3.min(channels, function (channel) {
        return d3.min(channel.DataRows, function (d) { return d.TimeStamp; });
    });
    // get X-Axis Max from all channels
    var tsMax = d3.max(channels, function (channel) {
        return d3.max(channel.DataRows, function (d) { return d.TimeStamp; });
    });

    // Test: offset 1 day 
    var tsMinOff = d3.time.day.offset(tsMin, -1)
    var tsMaxOff = d3.time.day.offset(tsMax, 1)

    xScale.domain([tsMinOff, tsMaxOff]);

    var bars = chGroup.selectAll(".bar").data(channel.DataRows);
    var barWidth = chartWidth / channel.DataRows.length;

    bars.enter().append("rect")
      .classed("bar", true)
      .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.TimeStamp) - (barWidth / 2); })
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(d.Value) })
      .attr("height", function (d) { return chartHeight - yScale(d.Value); })
       .style("fill", channel.Color);
```

thx...!!

[image]

Comment: Extend the chart by at least half the bar width. That is, increase the size of the domain by the corresponding value.

Comment: Hi Lars, sorry but how do you mean that with "extend the chart"...

Comment: Set the extremes of the x scale domain to whatever corresponds to the edge of the bars.

Comment: my x scale domain are timestamps, how can i manipulate that to corresponds with the bar edge? I was obviously missing the forest through the trees

Comment: It looks like it's months, so you could just add a month either way.

Comment: yes, the Time-View in the Screenshot are months. But you can switch in the toolbar to day, week, month, quarter and year. So, I can trigger a offset to my x-scale domain with d3.time.day.offset (min -1 max +1) for days, d3.time.month.offset (min -1 max +1) for months... and so on.

Comment: You could also get the difference between the first two bars and add that.